# something is missing when writing data into new tif file with gdal

Tags: python, tiff, gdal, geotiff, arcmap

There are problems in my writing data into .tif file with gdal module in python.
I want to extract data (numpy array) from a tif file and modify some of its values before saving it into a new one, with the new file functioning normally. I use following script:

```
tif = gdal.Open('data/pre_heilj_mean90_15.tif') #original tif file
imwidth = tif.RasterXSize
imheight = tif.RasterYSize
data = tif.ReadAsArray()
data[100][100] = 100 #modify value
data = data.astype(np.float32)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dataset = driver.Create('data/res.tif', imwidth, imheight, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
dataset.SetSpatialRef(tif.GetSpatialRef())
dataset.SetGeoTransform(tif.GetGeoTransform())
dataset.SetProjection(tif.GetProjection())
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)
dataset.FlushCache()
dataset=None
data=None
tif=None
```

I am certain that data in original tif file is 2-d and float32 type.
However, the new tif file(res.tif) is **all black** in ArcMap:
[res.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C8rQ.png)

Here is how the original tif file shows in ArcMap:
[original tif file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHW3j.png)
**And sizes of the two files differ a lot**, original is 5287KB and the new one is 4633KB.
I want to know what goes wrong.(forgive my poor English pls)

Comment: It may be worth asking in https://gis.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to write the nodata value in the metadata of the output file. The fact that it's "black" is probably just due to stretching, if you stretch the output similar (min = ~406) is should look similar.

For example get the nodata value with:

```py
nodata_value = tif.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
```

Then write/assign it with:

```py
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(nodata_value)
```

Keep in mind that this is a property of a band, so multiple bands in a single file can potentially have different nodata values.